# Saving modelform with user id?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have a question concerning a new project I'm creating. To put it simply, the website has user accounts, and each user has the ability to create a simple paragraph. The form is functioning perfectly, but I can't seem to assign the user's ID to the saved form.

model.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

class Thoughts(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150, default='')
    description = models.CharField(max_length=5000, default='')
```

forms.py

```
class ThoughtForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Thoughts
        fields = ['title', 'description']
```

views.py

```
@login_required(login_url='sign_in')
def add_thought(request):
    context = {}
    populateContext(request, context)

    user_details = UserProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
    context.update(user_details=user_details)

    if request.method == 'POST':
    new_thought_form = ThoughtForm(request.POST)

        if new_thought_form.is_valid():
            new_thought_form.save()
            return HttpResponse('Hurray, saved!')
    else:
        new_thought_form = ThoughtForm()


    c = {'new_thought_form': new_thought_form,}
    c.update(csrf(request))

    return render_to_response('lala/add_new_thought.html', c)
```

Whenever I try adding "instance=user_details.id", it says that the 'int' object has no attribute '_meta'. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can simplify the models by removing the `UserProfile` model:

```
# models.py

class Thoughts(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150, default='')
    description = models.CharField(max_length=5000, default='')
```

Your `forms.py` looks good.

Change your views:

```
# views.py     

@login_required(login_url='sign_in')
def add_thought(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ThoughtForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            thought = form.save(commit=False)
            thought.user = request.user
            thought.save()
            return HttpResponse('Hurray, saved!')
    else:
        form = ThoughtForm()
    return render(request, 'lala/add_new_thought.html', {
        'form': form
    })
```

Comment: Works! Thank you flowfree!